# How to define a custom Set implementation to be used for <set></set>

Tags: java, spring

While working with Spring i am facing a strange issue.i have a class which takes a set as an input since the class is of underlying framework so i can not change it.
Here is its declaration

```
private Set evaluate;

public Set getEvaluate()
    {
        return evaluate;
    }

public void setEvaluate(Set evaluate)
    {
        this.evaluate = evaluate;
    }
```

i am spring file i have following entry

```
<bean id="customService"
        class="com.platform.impl.DefaultFrameworkService"
        scope="tenant" parent="abstractService">
        <property name="evaluate">
            <set>
                <ref bean="bean1" />
                <ref bean="bean2" />
                <ref bean="bean3" />
                 <!-- inject new bean here. -->
                <ref bean="bean4" />
            </set>
        </property>
```

here `DefaultFrameworkService` takes set as input. so all i am trying is to inject a new bean to the underlying service.

My problem is when spring read this file it convert this `<set>` entry of sprong.xml to `LinkedHashSet` and than try to set these values to  `private Set evaluate` which ultimately throwing exception.

Though i can always override the `DefaultFrameworkService` and than can convert that `LinkedHashSet` to set but want to look for better way.

Exception i m getting is

```
Failed to convert property value of type 'java.util.LinkedHashSet' to required type 'java.util.Set' for property 'evaluate'
```

How can i make spring to pass value only as a `set` and not `LinkedHashSet`

**Update**

I was unable to set all these even so i played around a bit created a new customclass namely `CustomDefaultFrameworkService` with following implimentation

```
public class CustomDefaultFrameworkService extends DefaultFrameworkService
{

    Logger log = Logger.getLogger(CustomDefaultFrameworkService.class);
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private Set evaluate;

    /**
     * @param evaluateStrategies
     *           the evaluateStrategies to set
     */
    @Override
    public void setEvaluate(final Set evaluate)
    {
        log.info("Setting  values to super class. Total values being injected are " + evaluateStrategies.size());
        super.setEvaluate(evaluate);

    }
}
```

and i am able to set map to super class.This thing has made me more confused.

Comment: A `LinkedHashSet` "is a" `Set`. What error is it throwing?

Comment: Why would you want to use `<ref bean="bean3" /> twice within the same set, by the way? Perhaps that's what's failing?

Comment: @Bringer128:Please see my post i have updated it.

Comment: @JonSkeet:Sorry that was typo.Its a new bean, i corrected it.all i m trying is to hook that bean refrence to the underlying service

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`util` namespace](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/xsd-config.html), it element `set` has a parameter `set-class` where you can specify the implementation you want to use.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd">


<util:set id="emails" set-class="my.custom.set.implmentation">
    <value>pechorin@hero.org</value>
    <value>raskolnikov@slums.org</value>
    <value>stavrogin@gov.org</value>
   <value>porfiry@gov.org</value>
</util:set>

</beans>
```

@See [Spring Reference Chapter C.2.2.6](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/xsd-config.html#xsd-config-body-schemas-util-set)

Comment: Sorry, but first I do not understand the problem exactly. Do you belive that spring works for one class, but not for an other one? I guess there is some bug somewhere in your code. For example: your `CustomDefaultFrameworkService` has as setter that does not write to the field! So if you need support for a specific problem. First write an example application to make sure that the behaviour does not come form some other bean, then open a new question (with a deceptive title), describe the the behaviour, add the code,  add the spring configuration and the complete stack trace.